# Calendar days one day out

Tags: php

Will some help from this forum I have managed to get a week by week calendar up and running.  The only problem I have noticed is that all of the days are a day out.  All of Tuesday's days are showing as the beginning of the week

```
$display_week_ts = floor(time() / (3600 * 24)) * 3600 * 24;

$week_start = date('d-m-Y', $display_week_ts);
$week_number = date("W", $display_week_ts);
$year = date("Y", $display_week_ts);

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
  $current_day_ts = $display_week_ts + ($i * 3600 *24);
  $daily_date = date('d-m-Y', $current_day_ts);
  $StartDate =  date('d', $current_day_ts);
  $MonthName = date('m', $current_day_ts);
  $Year = date('Y', $current_day_ts);
  echo $daily_date;
 }
```

The dates at the beginning of the weeks ($daily_date) are all Tuesdays but of course they need to be Mondays (although I would prefer Sunday but that's not a crisis).

If I echo $week_start it seems that $display_week_ts is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

`$display_week_ts` is only the current day rounded down. To get the start of the week, you should use `strtotime("Monday midnight")`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am pretty new to php, where would I put that?

Comment: Instead of that long math-y thing you have.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but when it gets to the monday 29th October it shows that as a Tuesday instead, it skips a whole day and and then the calendar is out a day everyday after that

Comment: That would be because that's around when daylight savings ends. Try `noon` instead of `midnight`, that'll give plenty of leeway.

Comment: Hi, thanks again but no, it still skips a day when I use noon